# a sticky footer in a view instead of shell.html

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, durandal

I have a knockout and durandal app whose footer won't stick.
I believe this is because the footer is not specified in the shell.html

```
shell.htm
<div id="wrap" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static top" role="navigation"></nav>

  <div class="page-host" data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance', cacheViews: true }">

</div>
```

but specified in a view that composes other views.

```
wizard.html

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div data-bind="compose:{model:currentWizardView,activationData:$root,transition: 'entrance'}"></div>
</div>    
<div id="push"></div>
<div id="footer">
<div class="footer-bar">
    <button id="previous" class="btn btn-lg btn-next" data-bind="click:previous,enable:canMovePrevious">< Previous</button>
    <button id="next" class="btn btn-lg btn-next" data-bind="click:next,visible:canMoveNext">Next ></button>

</div>
```

The shell.html composes the wizard.html file.

So basically...

Shell.html wraps

1. Navbar
2. Composes Wizard

Wizard.html wraps

1. composes wizard view
2. footer

I have searched the web for days now and tried multiple css sticky footers (i.e.  navbar-fixed-bottom, position: fixed, vh - viewport height) do not give me the look I need.

I need the footer to be at bottom of page no matter the height of the composed view.

Any ideas?

The html... with fluff taken out.

```
<div id="applicationHost" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="wrap" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12" data-view="views/shell" data-active-view="true" style="">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static top" role="navigation">
        </nav>
        <div class="page-host" data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance', cacheViews: true }">
            <div class="container-fluid" data-view="views/wizard" data-active-view="true" style="">
                <div data-bind="compose:{model:currentWizardView,activationData:$root,transition: 'entrance'}">
                    <div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="views/texture" data-active-view="true" style="">
                        <div data-bind="compose:'templates/_value.html'">
                            <div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="views/templates/_value" data-active-view="true">
                                <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: values">
                                    <li class="list-group-item active" data-bind="click:$parent.setValue.bind($parent,$index()),css:{active: $parent.value() == $index()}">
                                        <label data-bind="text: $data"></label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="push"></div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <div class="footer-bar">
                        <button id="previous" class="btn btn-lg btn-next" data-bind="click:previous,enable:canMovePrevious">&lt; Previous</button>
                        <button id="next" class="btn btn-lg btn-next" data-bind="click:next,visible:canMoveNext">Next &gt;</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="views/serviceTypes" style="display: none;">
                <div class="row">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with the rendered html in it? That would make it easier to fix the CSS for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much a question of where in the lifecycle as one of page structure.

Durandal is completely orthogonal in the way it composes: the shell is a view/view-model pair just like everything else. The router manipulates the shell, composing views into it and managing their visibility. Probably the best way to see this is to get a working Durandal app and hit F12 on your browser, then watch what happens to the DOM as user actions cause views to load.

Every shell view contains some variation on this:

```
<div class="container page-host" data-bind="router: { cacheViews:true }"></div>
```

Notice the knockout binding to the router. This is what marshals views into the DOM. As a result, everything in any of your views is an indirect child of this div, and *this* is what is queering your attempts to position a footer.

You can solve the layout problem by re-parenting your footer div, but this gives you a new problem: visibility of the footer div will cease to depend on the view to which it logically belongs.

To bring the view's sticky footer back under automatic router control you will need to manage its parentage. You could do this with code in your view-model's activate and deactivate events, but a more elegant solution would be to data-bind its parentElement to a property of your view-model.

I imagine a sticky footer div will need to be an immediate child of `$(document.body)`